# Bulk mailing/mass mailing from Server

Tags: php, asp.net, email, cpanel

i need to send bulk mail in my php application, but its outgoing limit was 500, if i purchase VPS server for sending email if it grows more than 1000+  gmail /hotmail will mark me as a spam , so what is the solution for this issue?
{ purchasing api from mass providers is not  under my budget }

Comment: { purchasing api from mass providers is not under my budget } : then there is no way out. As mailing from common id will be blocked by the mail provider (will mark you as spammer) and at the reciever (junk mails or spam mails) end as well.

Comment: Do u have any cost effective provider to suggest?

Comment: Try purchasing mailing account not API for mailing.

Comment: for mailchimp both are same, do u have any suggestion, i need to integrate it with my own web application, so API is must

Answer (score 0):

If you think your mail is not spam and your mail server is not setup as a relay to others, then it is ok to go with a VPS server for the purpose.

In my case, I keep sending alerts to my customers on different conditions. The emails may amount to about 10000 a day. But I hear that these are blocked only in rare occasions and we ask the customers to add our from email to their address books and it becomes good after that.

Answer (score 0):

If your mail is not SPAM then you should be be able to deliver it, with some effort. Read for example [Gmail Bulk Senders Guidelines](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126).

One consideration is that you should not start with sending thousands of mails to gmail or any other mail provider. If their system does not know your server (specifically the IP address of your SMTP server), then it will block you. Start sending a few mails per day, and gradually increase the count.

I think VPS is only usable if you get your own dedicated IP address. Otherwise I would rent a dedicated server.

Comment: there is an option to get dedicated IP address from my service provider, but how it differ from  with out dedicate IP?

Comment: If you have a shared IP address and you get blocked, then every other customer on that address will be blocked and they will not like it. In the opposite direction it is also true, if somebody else gets blocked than you cannot deliver mail either. Moreover I believe that adapting to completely different mails is more difficult for the anti-spam system of the large providers.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you an idea,which might sound **WIERD !!!! and might lead you to pull hairs**.

Search for peter bromberg article in egghead cafe on Asynchronous Mail sending technique. Search on google if you can send messages from multiple account via single app. For example if your target for the day is 10000 mails, and per day limit for any common email id (or free version or lite version of any bulk mailing)  is say 500 then create an array of your email and assign them mail sending responsibility as per their limits. try to achieve this via your programming skills.

This is the only way i can suggest you in a very cost effective manner. But again you need minimum of 10-15 email ids for it, which is a biggest drawback of these approach.And you might need to create more 10-15 emails, if the earlier ones get blocked by your Service Provider or receivers SP.